# How to export the data from excel to word as text use VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have the following code found from this web site. It works almost, except that it export the date into a form in Word document. Instead, I would like to have paragraphs, keeping the original font, size and color in excel. Could anyone help? Very much appreciated!

```
Sub Export_Excel_To_Word()

Dim wdApp As Object
Dim wd As Object

On Error Resume Next
Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If
On Error GoTo 0

Set wd = wdApp.Documents.Add

wdApp.Visible = True



Sheets("sheet1").Activate
Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A2:F21")

Rng.Copy

   With wd.Range
        .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart                  'Slutet av dokumentet
        .InsertParagraphAfter                                 'Lagg till rad
        .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart                  'Slutet av dokumentet
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, False, False            'Paste with format

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What data is in the range `"A2:F21"`? Show a screenshot from your Excel document.

Comment: Could you try `.PasteSpecial WdPasteDataType.wdPasteText, False, False` ?

Comment: Documentation evidencing that  Dr. Application’s last name ’s has reviewed  XX  times for  Journal name
Documentation evidencing that  Dr. Application’s last name ’s has reviewed  XX  times for  Journal name
Documentation evidencing that  Dr. Application’s last name ’s has reviewed  XX  times for  Journal name
Documentation evidencing that  Dr. Application’s last name ’s has reviewed  XX  times for  Journal name

Comment: The comment does not allow screenshot. but here are the first few row.

Comment: Thanks, ASH. This gives an error code 424.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple, you're using the pasteSpecial method with misplaced parameters.  That induced me in error in the beginning. Try this to paste pure unformatted text:

```
.PasteSpecial DataType:=2 ' wdPasteDataType.wdPasteText
```

Or to keep the formats of fonts,

```
.PasteSpecial DataType:=1 ' wdPasteDataType.wdPasteRtf
```

To replace the tabs with single space after the paste:

```
With wd.Range
    .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
    .InsertParagraphAfter
    .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
    .PasteSpecial DataType:=2
    With .Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = vbTab
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.Text = " "
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindContinue
    End With
End With
```

Comment: .PasteSpecial DataType:=2 gets rid of the table, but leaves Tab mark between content of different cells. So there are extra spaces.   .PasteSpecial DataType:=1   still output a table. I do need to keep the fonts.

Comment: Yes Excel inserts tabs between cells. You want to replace them with singles spaces?

Comment: @VivianYu the last piece of the code above will paste text and will replace the `tabs` with single blanks after the pasting.

Comment: I want to keep the format. so Data Typse:=1 will be better. But I don't want the table. Ideally the content of each cell connect by single space and looks like a sentence.

Comment: Vivian Then I think you should consider the answer of @Slai, convert the table to text after pasting rtf format.

Comment: You are right. That worked. I am trying to figure out how to remove the hyphens, as Slai's method insert those between cells.

Comment: try to remove them using the `With .Find` bloc of my code. `.Text = chr(39)` and `.Replacement = ""`

Comment: Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest alternative that I can think of is to paste the Excel Range and convert the table to text:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("A2:F21").Copy

wdApp.Selection.Paste

wdApp.DefaultTableSeparator = " "

wdApp.Selection.Previous(15).Rows.ConvertToText
```

Comment: Thanks! this worked! Do you know how to remove the hyphen between the content of cells?

Comment: @VivianYu you can try the different optional parameters of the `.ConvertToText` method to see if that helps, or try the different options in the Convert Table To Text dialog and Record Macro to see the generated code.

Comment: Thanks very much!